# #1449 - phpMyAdmin (The user specified as a definer ('***'@'localhost') does not exist)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently transferring all of my 'Views' from a VPS hosted with 123-reg to another VPS provided by Heart Internet.

Here is the View:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`etd`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vShoppingCart` AS SELECT `VCoursesUOC`.`Distributor` AS `Distributor`,`VCoursesUOC`.`Company` AS `Company`,`VCoursesUOC`.`Title` AS `Title`,`VCoursesUOC`.`Price` AS `Price`,(`VCoursesUOC`.`Price` / 5) AS `VAT`,(`VCoursesUOC`.`Price` * 1.2) AS `WithVAT`,(sum(`VCoursesUOC`.`Price`) * 1.2) AS `Total`,count(`VCoursesUOC`.`CourseId`) AS `NoOfCourses` FROM `VCoursesUOC` WHERE (`VCoursesUOC`.`Payment` = 'Unpaid') GROUP BY `VCoursesUOC`.`Title`,`VCoursesUOC`.`Distributor`,`VCoursesUOC`.`Company`,`VCoursesUOC`.`Price`
```

Everytime I try to run this I get the following error:

```
#1449 - The user specified as a definer ('etd'@'localhost') does not exist
```

I have tried to change `etd` to root and a Database username on the MySQL Database but it does not fix the error.

What can I try?

I am logged in to phpMyAdmin as the root user.

Comment: the user is missing ??

Comment: But 'etd' has never existed on the new VPS so how does it know what user it is? I have tried changing 'etd' to the username linked to the database I am running it on and it still does not work.

Comment: try to create new user then try

Comment: But where is it getting `etd` from? :S

Comment: mysql> create user 'etd';

Comment: Follow these steps:

1.Go to PHPMyAdmin
2.Select Your Database
3.Select your table
4.On the top menu Click on 'Triggers'
5.Click on 'Edit' to edit trigger
6.Change definer from [user@localhost] to root@localhost

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer there are no triggers. It's a brand new VPS.

Comment: then you need to create user. you have a phpadmin panel or mysql cmd prompt??

Comment: **`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'etd'@'localhost'`.**  will return rows with a pretty good representation of the `GRANT` statements needed to create the user on another MySQL instance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply connect your database with MySQL workbench and follow the below steps -

1. Go to Administration tab
2. Click on Users and Privileges
3. Click on Add account button
4. On Add account page in Login tab add user with same username and password
5. Go to Administrative Roles tab select role as DBA and click on Apply button and you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The user does not exist, so you either need to create it or to use another user, which exists and has the necessary privileges.

etd is a user used at the original source as a definer.

Comment: How do I create the user?

Comment: @user6618037, please read this article, at the end you should be able to create a user: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 0):

The `DEFINER` is *optional* in the MySQL `CREATE VIEW` statement.

You could try modifying the statement to remove the `DEFINER = 'user'@'host'` from the statement.

That would be equivalent to specifying `DEFINER = CURRENT_USER` in the statement.

Given the `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`, this will impact the security context of the view.

---

If you want to specify a `DEFINER` in the view definition (in the `CREATE VIEW` statement), the specified user will need to exist in MySQL.

Note that a "user" in MySQL is identified by both a username *and* and host.

That is, `'etd'@'%'` is a *different* user than `'etd'@'localhost'`.

To create a user, you can run a statement like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'etd'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecretpassword'
```

This same user will also need to be granted appropriate SELECT privileges on the tables underlying the view,

---

To create a user on a MySQL instance, where you want to "copy" the definition from another MySQL instance to another...

On the "source" instance (where the `'etd'@'localhost'` user that we want to "copy" exists, we can run a statement like this statement:

```
 SHOW GRANTS FOR 'etd'@'localhost'
```

The rows returned by that are a pretty good representation of the statements we would need to run on another MySQL instance, to create the user there.

Comment: @spenser7593 The SHOW GRANTS shows: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'etd'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*RANDOMCODE'

Comment: @user6618037: You can take the output from the SHOW GRANTS statement (executed on the "source" instance, where you want to copy the user from), and take that over to *another* database instance, and execute those statements (add semicolons) to create the user. (I would note that "can't get it to work" is not particularly descriptive of the behavior you observe, as far as helping to identify the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

```
  select user, host from mysql.user;
```

You can use this command for getting your user and host information. If you are using root as user then try with ***root@localhost***